# Why aren't unsigned applets allowed to create custom ClassLoaders?

Tags: java, security, applet, classloader, unsigned

Java applets don't allow you to write a custom ClassLoader, unless you sign your applet.  Why is this so?  A custom ClassLoader is just a tool for *finding* classes.  You can't actually load the class except for by calling the private "defineClass" method, which is "trusted" code in the sense that it is written and controlled by the VM, not by your applet.  It's not like you gain any more permissions than the ability to dynamically load a class... Which really is nothing at all.

I guess as a side question:  Is there any other way to dynamically go from

```
byte[] => Class
```

which is allowed by unsigned applets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

defineClass has a ProtectionDomain parameter that you could pass with a PermissionCollection containing AllPermission, which would allow you to do basically anything to the host machine.

Comment: So, actually, wouldn't it be enough if this method throws an exception when the ProtectionDomain gives more rights than the loading code has?

Or simply restricts the rights to the intersection of current rights and the given ones (so the applet could load code with less permissions than itself has)?

Comment: That would be backwards-incompatible.  It is possible to solve the problem (java.lang.UntrustedClassLoader subclass, opt-in registration method, etc.), but such a mechanism doesn't currently exist.

Comment: Why would that be incompatible? If we made this change (security-check in defineClass instead of the constructor), what would break?

Comment: The JVM calls loadClass with arbitrary (potentially unprivileged) code on the call stack, so every custom class loader would have to use doPrivileged to ensure it was granting the appropriate privileges (and doing that would circumvent checkPackageAccess).  Even if the AccessControlContext from the constructor were saved, there undoubtably exist non-applet unprivileged class loader subclasses that use defineClass with AllPermission to increase their privileges, and that mechanism would break.

Comment: It really is just a feature the JVM is missing.  Even just a "defineClassUnprivledged" method would be fine, but they haven't implemented it.  There's a bug report about it which has been around for 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

Note, you can create a `ClassLoader` with `java.net.URLClassLoader.newInstance`. As pointed out by bkail, a custom `ClassLoader` could create classes with arbitrary permissions, as well as bypass other security constraints. As to why there isn't there isn't anything more general than `java.net.URLClassLoader.newInstance`, well there just isn't.